# Bootstrap 4 navbar is not toggling

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Hie, I have been trying to expand my responsive navbar using the data toggler however its not working , looked at other related questions but I have those issues covered ,maybe a second pair of eyes would do , my console is giving me a "string expected error".

I have already included my jquery ,bootstrap bundle and the bootstrap js in that order.
Using bootstrap 4 by the way thanks :)

```html
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light  bg-warning    px-5 py-0">

                       <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navmenu" >
                           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" ></span>
                       </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">

                        <ul class="navbar-nav ">

                        <li class="nav-item ">   <a class="nav-link " href="#">   Home               </a>    </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">   <a class="nav-link" href="#">     About us           </a>    </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">   <a class="nav-link" href="#">     Contact            </a>    </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">   <a class="nav-link" href="#">     Register           </a>    </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">   <a class="nav-link" href="#">     Virtual Classroom  </a>    </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your codes are working on me.
Can you paste those cdn addresses between body tags?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks CanUver I actually downgraded my jquery from 3.5 to 3.4 and it worked

Comment: Such things may be. I'm glad if I have been helpful. :)

Comment: I found out here on a separate issue that jQuery 3.5.0 was buggy, but 3.5.1 fixed those bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code with bootstrap 4 below have this snippet. You code is working. I found an issue in your understanding to bootstrap navbar collapsing. it's screen related or browser width. If you use `navbar-expand-md` `class` bootstrap navbar won't collapse until browser width less than or equal to `767.98px`.

**How it work navbar collapse?**

1. `navbar` without `navbar-expand-*` `class` navbar will collapse for
   all screen because bootstrap is mobile first design.
2. `navbar` with `navbar-expand-xl` `class` navbar will collapse only browser screen less than or equal to `1199.98px`.
3. `navbar` with `navbar-expand-lg` `class` navbar will collapse only browser screen less than or equal to `991.98px`.
4. `navbar` with `navbar-expand-md` `class` navbar will collapse only browser screen less than or equal to `767.98px`.
5. `navbar` with `navbar-expand-sm` `class` navbar will collapse only browser screen less than or equal to `575.98px`.

I suggest you to check your code in specific browser window. Use `Ctrl+Shift+I` for Chrome to open `inspect` element or you can use right click on mouse in `inspect` element. Then toggle device toolbar or `Ctrl+Shift+M` to check specific width.

Also check Bootstrap css in `head` `tag`. jQuery, Popper.js and Bootstrap.js will add respectively before end of the `body` `tag`. You should add meta view port in `head` tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light  bg-warning    px-5 py-0">

                       <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navmenu" >
                           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" ></span>
                       </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">

                        <ul class="navbar-nav ">

                        <li class="nav-item ">   <a class="nav-link " href="#">   Home               </a>    </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">   <a class="nav-link" href="#">     About us           </a>    </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">   <a class="nav-link" href="#">     Contact            </a>    </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">   <a class="nav-link" href="#">     Register           </a>    </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">   <a class="nav-link" href="#">     Virtual Classroom  </a>    </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: hie Rahul thanks for the suggestion , yes I did get the general sense of the navbar collapse feature however in my case It wasn't the problem anyways I managed to do a bit more digging and it turn out my jquery 3.5.0 wasn't working well with my bootstrap 4 , I managed to downgrade to 3.4 and the navbar worked as intended :)