# Navbar doesn't collapse to hamburger menu

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my Navbar responsible and when page is getting smaller navbar transforms to burger menu. It was working on a first try's but now it's not transforming to hamburger menu. My buttons and switch just disappears from navbar when screen goes smaller.

```
           <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
          <a class="navbar-brand"><i class="far fa-chart-bar"></i></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="news/news.html">News</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul> 
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- Here is a switch for Light/Dark mode -->
            <div class="theme-switch-wrapper" id="switch">
                <label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
                    <div class="slider round"></div>
              </label>
              <em></em>
            </div>

        </nav>
```

CSS

```
.navbar.navbar-expand-lg { 
background-color:#6b7fdf;
height: 55px;
width: 100%;
}
.nav-link.dropdown-toggle {
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
margin-right: 0 auto;
}
.navbar-brand {
 margin-top: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: Look like you use bootstrap4. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61428942/bootstrap-4-navbar-is-not-toggling/61442401#61442401

Comment: @Rahul Hey! Thank for comment, i checked your link and my problem is little bit different i think, navbar collapsing at 998px but the links as Home/News just disappear without transforming to hamburger menu, maybe it's a css problem?

Comment: I add ans. If this ans will not fix your issue. Please share your custom `CSS` for `navbar`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `HTML` markup like this. You have two `ul` closing tag `</ul>` it's incorrect.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand"><i class="far fa-chart-bar"></i></a>

    <!-- Here is a switch for Light/Dark mode | For Mobile -->
    <div class="theme-switch-wrapper d-lg-none" id="switch">
        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="news/news.html">News</a>
            </li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
    <!-- Here is a switch for Light/Dark mode | for Desktop -->
    <div class="theme-switch-wrapper d-none d-lg-block" id="switch">
        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar.navbar-expand-lg { 
background-color:#6b7fdf;
  height: auto;
width: 100%;
}
.nav-link{
  color: white;
}
.nav-link.dropdown-toggle {
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
margin-right: 0 auto;
}
.navbar-toggler{
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
}
```

You have to add custom `CSS` for `navbar-toggler` and `switch`. My `HTML` markup format is correct.

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/abvwVWx).

Desktop view:

[image: Desktop view]

Mobile view:

[image: Mobile view]

Comment: check my ans with CSS included.

Comment: Why you add your custom `CSS` in ans field. It should be in where you ask the question.

Comment: @Hexynator please check. You have forgot to add custom css for `navbar-toggler` and `switch`. You can use bootstrap 4 switch https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#switches